# React SVG child component cant pass it react event onMouseEnter

Tags: reactjs, svg, events, jsx

**What I try to achieve, when mouse enters a segment of a Donut Chart I want to show its label**.
Cant currently even make it console.log when it enters near it,

*What I have tried* : wrapping the segment in divs and this only made the segments stop rendering

I cant seem to be able to use onMouseEnter to even console.log('hello')

```
import React from "react";
import SegmentComponent from "./SegmentComponent";
import DonutGraphLabel from "./DonutGraphLabel";
import StyledDonutGraph from "./donutGraph.style";

const DonutGraph = ({ colors, values, icons, initialOffset }, ...props) => {
  let valueSum = 0;

  const getOffset = function (value) {
    let thisOffset;
    if (valueSum === 0) {
      thisOffset = initialOffset;
    } else {
      thisOffset = 100 - valueSum + initialOffset;
    }
    valueSum += value;
    return thisOffset;
  };

  return (
    <StyledDonutGraph>
      {values.map((item, idx) => {
        return <DonutGraphLabel item={item} color={colors[idx]} />;
      })}
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" className="donut">
        <circle
          className="donut-hole"
          cx="21"
          cy="21"
          r="15.91549430918954"
          fill="transparent"
        ></circle>
        <circle
          className="donut-ring"
          cx="21"
          cy="21"
          r="15.91549430918954"
          fill="transparent"
          stroke="#d2d3d4"
          strokeWidth="3"
        ></circle>
        {values.map((segment, idx) => {
          const calculatedOffset = getOffset(segment.value);
          return (
            <div onMouseEnter={console.log("hola Yulia")}>
              <SegmentComponent
                key={idx}
                onClick={console.log(segment.label)}
                color={colors[idx]}
                value={segment.value}
                offset={calculatedOffset}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </svg>
    </StyledDonutGraph>
  );
};

export default DonutGraph;
```

Comment: to put a div in SVG the div must have a foreignObject element as its parent.

Comment: I do not quite get what you are telling me, could you please give me an example? in my current approach this svg is encapsulated in a React component

Comment: I am sorry Robert, I have updated what my component is like, I do know what a Parent is, I do not understand what foreignObject is , I just want to know what else needs to be done for me to be able to use this events

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/extend.html#EmbeddingForeignObjects

Comment: I have tried following what the docu said, however when I wrap my Segments in it, they stop rendering, considering I only want this divs to be able to pass my segments events, I do not think this is the solution I am looking for